# How to convert string to objectId in LocalField for $lookup Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, join, lookup

I want to add join collections using `$lookup` in mongodb. I am trying as below

```
{
 $lookup:{
   from:"User",
   localField:"assignedId",
   foreignField:"_id",
   as:"dataa"}
}
```

Now I have two collections

**User** contains `objectid` of users like  `"_id" : ObjectId("56ab6663d69d2d1100c074db"),`

and  **Tasks** where it contains `assignedId` as a `string` `"assignedId":"56ab6663d69d2d1100c074db"`

Now, when applying $lookup in both collection its not working because Id's are not matching.

For that I googled it and found a solution that to include

`{ $project: { assignedId: {$toObjectId: "$assignedId"} }}`

but this solution is not working for me, Its throwing an error:

```
assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$toObjectId'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed
```

Please help me how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible in the aggregation pipeline. There is no method to convert the type.
Can you change the type of "assignedId" in the Tasks collection to ObjectId ?
Else you have to do it in code, convert the ObjectId to a String and use in in another query.

Comment: OK..... suppose in tasks collection I do `"assignedId":ObjectId("56ab6663d69d2d1100c074db")` and now I want to get tasks on the basis of assignedId then how I can write query for that...`Task.find({assignedId:ObjectId("56ab6663d69d2d1100c074db")},function(err,data){....})`

Comment: When you loop through the results you can do "toString()" on the property to convert the ObjectId => String so you can use it in the next find. like : Task.find({assignedId : yourvar.toString()}, function(err,data){....})

Comment: I mean ,I have ownerId like `56ab6663d69d2d1100c07‌​4db` and now I want to fetch data from `tasks` collection `Task.find({assignedId : ownerId}, function(err,data){....})` but in tasks collection I have `assignedId` like  `ObjectId("56ab6663d69d2d1100c07‌​4db")` then how it will work? how to its will match id's

Comment: @SaurabhSharma You can convert a string => ObjectId using : 
var objectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
var MyObjectId = new objectId('yourstringobjectid');

Comment: Thanks ...Its working

Comment: You can't do it in this moment, the request to Mongodb here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781

Comment: It is possible in 4.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51903659/772290 for answer.