# How can I merge two mongo collections?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am banging my head against the wall on this...

**SEE UPDATE 1 (below) !**

I am merging two collections together... I looked at this example ( and ~several~ other examples here on SO ... )

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-single-equality

I think I am really close, but my expected results are not the same as what I would expect out of the example.

Here is the schema for 'Event'

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
})
```

Here is some 'Event' data

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
        "name": "358 Event"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e8e55c5a0f5fc1431453b5f",
        "name": "b5f Event"
    }
]
```

Here is 'MyEvent' schema:

```
const MyEventSchema = new Schema({

    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    eventId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
})
```

Here is some 'MyEvent' data

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e8f4ed2ddab5e3d04ff30b3",
        "userId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b",
        "eventId": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
    }
]
```

Here is my code ( the code is wrapped in a promise so it returns resolve and reject with data )

```
   var agg = [
       {
         $lookup:
           {
             from: "MyEvent",
             localField: "_id",
             foreignField: "eventId",
             as: "userIds"
           }
       }
    ];

   Event.aggregate(agg)
   .then( events => {
       return resolve(events);
   })
   .catch(err => {
       return reject(null);
   })
```

Here are my results,

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
        "name": "358 Event",
        "__v": 0,
        "UserIds": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e8e55c5a0f5fc1431453b5f",
        "name": "b5f Event",
        "__v": 0,
        "UserIds": []
    }
]
```

I expect to see UserIds filled in for event '358 Event', like this
What am I missing ???

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
        "name": "358 Event",
        "__v": 0,
        "UserIds": [
          {"userId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b"}
         ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e8e55c5a0f5fc1431453b5f",
        "name": "b5f Event",
        "__v": 0,
        "UserIds": []
    }
]
```

**UPDATE 1**

I found a mongo playground and what I have works there, but it doesn't work in my code ??

https://mongoplayground.net/p/fy-GP_yx5j7

In case the link breaks, here is configuration:  * select 'bson multiple collections'

```
db={
  "collection": [
    {
      "_id": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
      "name": "358 Event"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e8e55c5a0f5fc1431453b5f",
      "name": "b5f Event"
    }
  ],
  "other": [
    {
      "_id": "5e8f4ed2ddab5e3d04ff30b3",
      "userId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b",
      "eventId": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",

    }
  ]
}
```

Here is Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "other",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "eventId",
      as: "userIds"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
    "name": "358 Event",
    "userIds": [
      {
        "_id": "5e8f4ed2ddab5e3d04ff30b3",
        "eventId": "5e8e4fcf781d96df5c1f5358",
        "userId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e8e55c5a0f5fc1431453b5f",
    "name": "b5f Event",
    "userIds": []
  }
]
```

any suggestions as to why this doesn't work in my code... but works in the playground?

**UPDATE 2**

I found this:

[Need a workaround for lookup of a string to objectID foreignField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573276/need-a-workaround-for-lookup-of-a-string-to-objectid-foreignfield?rq=1)

**UPDATE 3**

I have changed the schema to use ObjectId for ids now
still doesn't work

And they are ObjectIds :

[image]

**RESOLUTION:**

So the real answer was a combination of Update 2 and Update 3 and using the right collection name in the lookup.

Update 2 is pretty much my very same question... just using different table names

**Update 3 is the correct way to solve this issue.**

Mohammed Yousry pointed out the collection name might be wrong... so I looked at my schema and I did have it wrong - changed the name to the right name (along with ObjectId types) and it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a typo in `from` property in `$lookup`, `MyEvent` maybe not the collection name

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "MyEvent", // here is the issue I think, check the collection name and make sure that it matches the one you write here
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "eventId",
      as: "userIds"
    }
  }
])
```

in mongo playground you attached in the question, if you change the 'other' in the $lookup to anything else, or make a typo in it .. like `others` instead of `other`, you will face the same issue

so check that there is no typo in the word `MyEvent` that you populate from

Comment: well... if you create the schema and name it 'MyEvent' there will not be an issue with that.

Comment: I didn't mean that there is an issue with the name 'MyEvent' Schema, I meant maybe there is a typo in this collection name, maybe it is 'myEvent' not 'MyEvent', I mean in the $lookup not in the naming, you can name the schema as you want of course,

Comment: that's not it. it has to do with strings and object ids... as the mongodb playground works perfectly

Comment: could you try to use mongo playground with the same names of your Schemes? rather than using 'collection' use 'Event', and rather than 'other' use the second scheme name 'MyEvent', and try it

Comment: also, could you show how did you require this collection 'MyEvent' in the file where you did the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: okay great, the collection name is '**MyEvents**' .. not 'MyEvent' that's what i was trying to say, hope it will work as expected now

Comment: well... sort of ... my collection isn't even named 'MyEvent' or 'MyEvents'  it is named 'it_repo'  and I was using 'itrepo'... so you put me on the right track

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12371475/mohammed-yousry - Was this a good question?  did it outline all of the necessary information required for you to come up with an answer?  If so, can you please up vote it?  thanks