# MongoDB $lookup on 2 level nested document without using $unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents

**loanRequest** (Writing just the keys that I want to project)

```
{
  "_id": "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea592",
  "lendingpartner": { 
     /* some keys here */
  },
  "loans": [
    {
      "loanid": 43809,
      "loanamount": 761256,
      "jewels": [
        "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea593",
        "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea594"
        "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea595"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

**pledgedJewel**

```
{
  "_id": "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea593",
  "netweight": 8.52,
  "purity": 19,
}
```

---

What I want to achieve is

```
{
  "_id": "5f2bf2b583f65d33026ea603",
  "lendingpartner": { 
     /* some keys here */
  },
  "loans": [
    {
      "loanid": 40010,
      "loanamount": 100000,
      "jewels": [
        {
          "_id": "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea593",
          "netweight": 8.52,
          "purity": 19,
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea594",
          "netweight": 5.2,
          "purity": 40,
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f2bf26783f65d33026ea595",
          "netweight": 4.52,
          "purity": 39,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Since I want the jewel details to be populated inside the jewels array of each loan, `$unwind` would not help me. (I tried experimenting with it)

I thought I could run a `$map` on loans array and then run `$lookup` for each jewel of the loan(double map?), but could not come up with a workable solution.
That didn't seem to be the right approach anyway.

---

This is the best I could come up with (Far from my desired result). I'm using map to selectively pick keys from loans object.

```
const loanrequests = await db.collection('loanrequest').aggregate([
  { $match: { requester: ObjectID(user.id) } },
  {
    $project: {
      lendingpartner: {
        name: 1,
        branchname: '$branch.branchname',
      },
      loans: {
        $map: {
          input: '$loans',
          as: 'loan',
          in: {
            loanid: '$$loan.loanid',
            loanamount: '$$loan.amount',
            jewels: '$$loan.jewels',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  /*
  * I experimented with unwind here. Tried adding 
  * { $unwind: '$loans' },
  * { $unwind: '$loans.jewels' }
  * but it does not give me the result I need (as already said before)
  */
]).toArray();
```

I figure, I need to do the `$lookup` before the projection, but I'm it hard to write a workable solution due to 2 level nested structure of the document (First, the `loans` array and then `loans.jewels`)

I started working with mongodb aggregators today and while looking for answers, I stumbled upon a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953780/lookup-multiple-levels-without-unwind) but it seemed more complex and hence harder for me to understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@GitGitBoom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287582/3728336) in the previous answer, `$unwind` followed by `$group` should have been the approach.

Ofcourse, prior to grouping (I think of it as "unspreading" the outcome of running unwind), I needed to run `$lookup` in order to populate `loans.jewels`

Here is the entire solution build on top of the previous answer.

```
const loanRequests = await db.collection('loanRequest').aggregate([
  { $match: { requester: ObjectID(user.id) } },
  {
    $project: {
      lender: '$lendingpartner.name',
      branch: '$lendingpartner.branch.branchname',
      loans: 1,
    },
  },
  { $unwind: '$loans' },
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: 'loans.jewels',
      from: 'pledgedJewel',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'loans.jewels',
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      branch: { $first: '$branch' },
      lender: { $first: '$lender' },
      loans: { $push: '$loans' },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      branch: 1,
      lender: 1,
      loans: 1,
    },
  },
]).toArray();
```

---

### Issue with mismatch of types

Another issue was, my `$lookup` was not working due to mismatch of types. In loanRequest collection, on which I'm running the aggregate, the ids inside `loans.jewels` are of type `string` whereas the foreign field `_id` in pledgedJewel is an `ObjectId`

This can be solved by using `$toObjectId` or `$toString` (only supported in mongodb version >= 4.0)

```
{ $project: { jewelObjId: { $toObjectId: '$loans.jewels' } } },   // for mongodb >= 4.0
{
  $lookup: {
    localField: 'jewelObjId',  // for mongodb >= 4.0
    from: 'pledgedjewel',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'loans.jewels',
  },
},
```

But, I was running on a lower version of mongodb, hence these aggregations were not working for me. Only solution to this was to change the type of `loans.jewels` to `ObjectId` instead of keeping it as `string` which I did.

### More on type mismatch

[Need a workaround for lookup of a string to objectID foreignField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573276/need-a-workaround-for-lookup-of-a-string-to-objectid-foreignfield)

[Mongodb Join on _id field from String to ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093647/mongodb-join-on-id-field-from-string-to-objectid)

Answer (score 1):

If there are not other things you are trying to achieve with aggregate you can use .populate in mongoose.

```
LoanReqests
  .find(
    {requester: user.id},
    {name: 1, branch: 1, loans: 1} // Projection
  )
  .populate('loans.jewels');
```

If you have to use aggregate to do something not in your example, then $unwind is really your best bet, but then $grouping after the $lookup to get the output you desire. If this doesn't work for you, can you expand on what the issue with $unwind is? I am guessing it is to do with fields not listed in your question.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/O5pxWNy99J4

```
db.loanRequests.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      loans: 1,
      branch: "$branch.name"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$loans"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: "loans.jewels",
      foreignField: "_id",
      from: "jewels",
      as: "loans.jewels"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      branch: {
        $first: "$branch"
      },
      loans: {
        $push: "$loans"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: You're right, `$unwind` followed by `$group` leads to the desired output. Not being aware of `$group` previously, I was kind of clueless on how to "unspread" (after running $unwind). I tried building up on your solution, and got the desired result.